# Listing large number of files in multi level directories

Tags: c#, sql

I've got quite a big problem.  I have a drive with nearly 600,000 files on it within various levels of folders and I need to create an SQL table with a list of filepaths but not for all of the files.

The structure is:

```
J:/
J:/test
J:/XCR
J:/554
J:/B1
```

I need to keep all the files in the folders test & XCR but only files within certain directories in the other folders.  I have a list of these folders uploaded to an SQL table.

I've written a recursive function that uses Directory.GetFiles() and Directory.GetDirectories but I encounter problems when the directory levels increase and the filenames get longer.   I've also have the following error that I'm not sure about...

```
System.IO.IOException: Element not found. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath
```

I think I'm going about this the wrong way.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
 public void copyFiles(string dirName, int level)
{
    try
    {


    if (level == 1)
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dirName))
        {
            Response.Write(f + "<br />");
         //   insTbl.Rows.Add(f);
        }
    }

    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dirName))
    {

        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
        {
            Response.Write(f + "<br />");
         //   insTbl.Rows.Add(f);
        }

        level++;

        copyFiles(d,level);
    }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your recursive code.

Comment: The Win API for folders can only handle a maximum folder length (I forget what it is). You are using Directory.GetDirectories which includes the full path of the folder - this will probably cause Directory.GetFiles to crash eventually. Try getting the relative folder names and using those to get the files relative to that folder rather than keep using the full path.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I think.  How do I then get the full path for the file?